# Questions about double install of Python on OSX

Tags: python

As we all know; Apple ship OSX with Python, but it locks it away.

This force me and anyone else that use python, to install another version and start the painful process of installing with pip with 100 tricks and cheats.

Now, I would like to understand how to do this right; and sorry but I can't go with the route of the virtualenv, due to the fact that I run this for a build server running Jenkins, and I have no idea how to set that up correctly.

Could you please clarify for me these?

1. How do you tell OSX to run the python from brew, instead than system one?
2. Where is the official python living, and where are the packages installed, when I run `pip install` with and without the `-U` and/or the `--user` option?
3. In which order should I install a bunch of packages starting from scratch.on a fresh OSX machine,so I can set it up reliably every time?

Mostly I use opencv, scikit-image, numpy, scipy and pillow. These are giving me so many issues and I can't get a reliable setup so that Jenkins is happy to run the python code, using these libraries.

Answer (score 0):

1. Brew installs packages into `/usr/local/Cellar` and then links them to `/usr/local/bin (i.e. /usr/local/bin/python3)`. In my case, I just make sure to have `/usr/local/bin in my PATH prior to /usr/bin`.

   `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`
2. By using brew, your new packages will be installed to:

   `/usr/local/Cellar/python`

   or

   `/usr/local/Cellar/python3`
3. Package install order shouldn't matter.

Comment: Stupid formatting.  Yeah, that came out way louder than intended.  My first answer.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to brew is MacPorts. You can install MacPorts by following the instructions at https://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.macports.html

Once MacPorts is installed, you can use "port install python27" or "port install python36" for different python versions. If you are not the user "root", you should use "sudo port install python27" or "sudo port install python36" to install and type the root password when prompted.

The command "which python" will tell you where the current active python is installed. If it's something like with "/usr/bin/python", it means you have installed your own python via MacPorts, because Apple's pre-installed python usually has a long path starting with "/Library".

You can use "port search xyz" for any software you want to install, and use "port list" to list all the software installed by MacPorts. Use "man port" to see all the port commands available.

Usually, the order of the packages you install via "pip" does not matter. You can use "pip search xyz" to search the packages you want and "pip list" to list all the python packages installed by pip. Use "pip -h" to show all the available pip commands. Like "port", you should use "sudo pip install xyz" if you are not the user "root" and type the root password. To find out who you are, type the command "whoami".